# How to model data when using Room

Tags: android, android-room

I am reading up on Room and the way it handles relationships between entities is both understandable, but confusing. I cannot wrap my head around what a "proper" data model should be to make Room happy. The problem is that all the examples I have found show how to handle a simple relationship, but don't address nesting, or entities that contain references to multiple other entities.

Going back to the beginning, my question is how should I model my data to make using Room as easy as possible?

1. Is it possible to have the data model framework-agnostic? That's something that feels correct to me. A framework should not dictate the way entities are modeled. I want to be able to traverse the data model as I would if there was no database at all.
2. Assuming I have a deep-ish hierarchy, for example: a `Game` has multiple `Players` and multiple `Rounds`. A `Round` has multiple `Turns`. A `Turn` can have multiple `Steps`. How do I model this according to Room? Reading about `@Relation`, it would suggest there should be "wrapper" POJOs. But would that mean that here I would have to create classes `TurnWithSteps`, `RoundWithTurnWithSteps`, and `GameWithRoundWithTurnWithSteps`?
3. This also seems to imply that whenever working with the entities in code, I have to decide which "view" of that entity to use. So I cannot simply work with `Game` and use it as if it was a true, nicely modeled class?

Comment: > Is it possible to have the data model framework-agnostic? -- that depends on what you mean by "the data model". If you mean the Room entities, no, as they get littered with Room annotations. I (and others) have been recommending treating Room entities the same way that you would treat Retrofit responses and similar things: as representations from an external data source that populate models but are not models themselves.

Comment: "I want to be able to traverse the data model as I would if there was no database at all" -- that would be your own set of model objects, which you would populate from the Room entities, but they would not be the Room entities themselves.